# How to store file with local path in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am a React native developer and I was trying to integrate a native ios code.

One of the instance takes `NSURL *` which should be a local path I  guess

https://github.com/uber/startup-reason-reporter/blob/master/StartupReasonReporter/StartupReasonReporterPriorRunInfo/UBApplicationStartupReasonReporterPriorRunInfo.h#L21

```
+ (nonnull instancetype)priorRunAtDirectoryURL:(nullable NSURL *)directoryURL;
```

I am not sure what does localPath Url looks like in IOS, like what should I pass? for example?

Ps: intentionally including swift tag as well because I think swift developers could also answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on description of that function:

> - Returns the prior run information stored to disk at the given directory URL.
> - @param directoryURL The directory to use to to store the startup reason data.
> - @return the previous startup reason data if it was present on disk, or empty startup reason object.
>   */

you need to provide a directory they can write into. So Apps's document directory would be the best (as a root) + whatever folder you want (which, based on their code, they will even create for you).
So:

```
NSURL* docs = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL* myCrashes = [docs URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myCrashes" isDirectory:TRUE];
```

it will look something like:

```
file:///some/path/to/app/sandbox/data/Documents/myCrashes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up documentation for

```
- (NSArray<NSURL *> *)URLsForDirectory:(NSSearchPathDirectory)directory 
                         inDomains:(NSSearchPathDomainMask)domainMask;`
```

That will get you the URL and check out FileManager.SearchPathDirectory enum for all the viable options:

Here's an example for getting the caches directory

```
NSURL* url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];`
```

It could be any one of the 25-26 options in SearchPathDirectory depending on where they put that stuff.

Comment: he needs to store something there for the next invocation of the app. Cache directory can be cleared between invocations - not a great option for this use case.